# how to get the modified values from a replica of table in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have created a table from another table like this

```
CREATE TABLE newtable LIKE oldtable; 
INSERT INTO newtable SELECT * FROM oldtable;
```

and inserted a new column in newly created table. Is there any way i can keep record of data modified or added in old table and update it on new table.

Comment: Why take a copy and then keep both tables values updated?

Comment: same db?,same schema?, same server?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6152400/p-salmon yes

Answer (score 0):

Create a trigger to old table which updates the new one.